# Drawing Matches of SuperGlue with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, keypoint, magic-leap

I'm trying to use OpenCV's `cv.drawMatches()` function to draw the keypoint matches of SuperGlue.

`drawMatches()` has parameters keypoints1, keypoints2 and matches, that are in different form from SuperGlue's.

SuperGlue simply outputs the coordinates of the keypoints, but opencv is creating keypoint objects. And there's a converter of that in OpenCV, `pts = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(kp)` that works fine.

However, I didn't see any converter for the `matches` parameter.

SuperGlue outputs something like this:

```
array([ -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,   8,  -1,  -1,  25,  -1,  24,  -1,  21,  -1,
    28,  29,  -1,  -1,  32,  -1,  -1,  -1,  45,  37,  44,  -1,  -1,
    -1,  -1,  50,  -1,  53,  -1,  48,  60,  -1,  -1,  -1,  59,  64,
    -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  70,  71,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  82,  -1,
```

But opencv outputs a DMatch object, like this:

```
(<DMatch 0000021FD87A3690>,
 <DMatch 0000021FEF895110>,
 <DMatch 0000021FEF894BF0>,
 <DMatch 0000021FEF894E10>,
```

I tried to put the matches of the SuperGlue to the `cv.drawMatches()`, got an error like this:

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'drawMatches'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'matches1to2'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'matches1to2'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

Is there any way to convert the SuperGlue's match type to OpenCV's?

Or, in general, is there a way to draw the SuperGlue Matches with OpenCV?

Thanks.

Comment: what do those numbers coming from "SuperGlue" even mean? _what is "SuperGlue"?_

Comment: SuperGlue is a pretrained AI model that finds keypoints and matching them.